# ckeditor inherit parent class(style)

Tags: css, validation, inheritance, ckeditor, styles

I use ckeditor in html form. Ckeditor is use on textarea field. When I send form and textarea field is empty PHP validation add class "is-invalid" to textarea field. Is possible inherit this "is-invalid" class to ckeditor ?

I have:

```
<textarea class="form-control **is-invalid**" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
<div id="cke_content" class="cke_1 cke cke_reset is-invalid cke_chrome cke_editor_content cke_ltr cke_browser_webkit" dir="ltr" lang="cs" role="application" aria-labelledby="cke_content_arialbl">
... 
</div>
```

I need:

```
<textarea class="form-control" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
<div id="cke_content" class="**is-invalid** cke_1 cke cke_reset is-invalid cke_chrome cke_editor_content cke_ltr cke_browser_webkit" dir="ltr" lang="cs" role="application" aria-labelledby="cke_content_arialbl">
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about  using JavaScript validation and check the textarea before sending form then set that class to textarea and div